# Bootstrap row hanging out past containing div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a front-end dev so I really have very little experience with html/css, but I was asked to try to implement a new page in a web portal for someone and I'm kind of stuck.

The basic idea is I have something like:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <!--stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="container-fluid block-container">
          <!--Stuff-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem comes because the row is hanging outside of the panel horizontally, matching the page width instead of the panel width.

Example image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkqKg.jpg  (I added the border around .block-container to demonstrate)

I feel like this should be easy to fix, but nothing I've come across has worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bootstrap `.row` has negative margins, so you should place the row inside `.panel-body`...

```
<div class="panel">
     <div class="panel-heading">
                <!--stuff-->
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="row">
               <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="block-container">

                     </div>
               </div>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly like I expected.  Not sure why I didn't think of that, just comes with not being familiar enough with bootstrap I guess.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Add a div wrapping everything with the class `.container` in fact add that class here:

```
<div class="page container">
```

Comment: I withdraw from the running and endorse the nearly 100k rep guy with my "daily vote limit reached" vote ;)

Comment: haha cheers mate, I appreciate that, I will even come back tomorrow for the upvote ;) Hey was my answer completely wrong? Yours seems "panel specific" but would mine have worked? I thought it would when posted it haha

Comment: I tried yours too, but it didn't quite work as expected.  I can show you the screenshots if you're interested in what happened instead.

Comment: When I added container to the "page" div:  http://i.imgur.com/SzuzPGb.png

Comment: I also tried adding it to the "panel" div instead of page:  http://i.imgur.com/ZQRzlL8.png  You'll notice in both cases that there's a lot of extra space around the outside of the panel that wasn't there before.  Presumably because of some conflict witht he way I have the individual containers already set up, so setting it as a container is shrinking the container to match the contents